# How to autosart on boot CAN program written in C

Tags: c, raspberry-pi3, can-bus, canutils

I am making CAN bus simulator, everything works if i start it manually. Tried adding into /etc/rc.local   sudo ./canfinal, tried adding sudo /home/pi/canfinal. none of these work for somereason, any ideas why?

I would like raspberry to start sending CAN bus data as soon as it startsup using my written program

Comment: Does you program write out some logging information? This would be very useful (write what your program does to the system log or to a file, so we can have a base to debug from). For example use [this library](https://github.com/rxi/log.c)

Comment: hi, the program itself works, no problems, no bugs. I just dont know how to autostart it when raspberry start , because rs.local metod does not work. Can there be a problem because it uses loopback mode or because it uses SPI interface?

Comment: It is possible, but we would need to know what exactly fails in the program (I assume it requires something which is not available yet), which is why a log is important.